# Why did NoScript in my TorBrowser change to "Allow all scripts Globally" on its own?

Tags: ubuntu, browsers, noscript

Today I noticed that NoScript in TorBrowser has allowed all scripts globally! I've had them disabled by default ever since I formated the disc. I didn't change any NoScript settings. Both my laptop's and desktop's Tor Browser changed to "Allow Scripts Globally" **today** on their own.

Tor Browser 6.0.5 was released 5 days ago, but the [release notes](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-605-released) didn't mention the above behavior.

---

I had initially installed Firefox, then NoScript (with "Forbid Scripts Globally"), and finally Tor Browser. Could it be that NoScript from my Firefox interacted with Tor Browser?

Or have both my machines been compromised?

Comment: I'd guess you set it manually, while keeping the tor button security slider at low and the new torbutton version set the settings back to low. set the security slider to high.